# ASP.NET MVC Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I imported an MVC 4 project that uses roles to control permissions to access different pages and blocks. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web with Update 4.

However, I am getting the following error when I run the project (I have not modified anything yet). It uses the statement `@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("[RoleName]")` to show certain parts of the page.

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : {"Invalid objet name 'webpages_UsersInRoles'."}`

I believe it could be because the database is empty (thus no roles have been defined). However, I tried to manually add roles and assign them to users using Server Explorer

I am able to login and register using the MVC template pages, but when I open any page that contains that statement I get the error and the app crashes.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point at the function "IsUserInRole" and seeing what that object is that it's trying to work with 'webpages_UsersInRoles'?  If it's a table/stored procedure then the object needs to be created in the database

Answer (score 0):

I found some additional documentation on the simple membership with MVC 4. There are indeed some tables that MVC needs in order to do this membership and one of them is webpages_UsersInRoles.

Have you tried **Registering** an account? It seems that should call the initialize method to create the tables in the database.

Check this link for more info:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/689801/Understanding-and-Using-Simple-Membership-Provider

Answer (score 0):

If this app is intended to use windows authentication and you are running under IIS express it may be as simple as turning the windows authentication flag to "true".

Comment: It's not using Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid objet name error is related to sql server when table,store procedure is missing.
Just check in Database if table is present [database].[schema].[tablename]